# Pandas apply with argument that varies by row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that contains 50 rows, for example the BCI data from R.

```
import pandas.rpy.common as com
varespec = com.load_data('BCI', 'vegan')
```

I am attempting to apply a function to each row, where the function takes a 'size' argument.

```
def rare(y, size):
    notabs = ~np.isnan(y)
    t = y[notabs]
    N = np.sum(t)
    diff = N - t
    rare = np.sum(1 - comb(diff, size)/comb(N, size))
    return rare
```

If size is an integer, it works fine:

```
varespec.apply(rare, axis=1, args=(20,))
```

What I would like to do is make size an array of 50 elements that all differ, so that each row has a unique value of size. If I make size a vector of 50, it passes the entire vector and the function doesn't work. How can I make

```
varespec.apply(rare, axis=1, args=(size,))
```

use a unique element of size for each row? I can do for loops:

```
for i in xrange(50):
    rare(varespec.iloc[i,:], size[i])
```

but is there a better way using apply functions?

Comment: Is `comb` the `scipy.misc.comb` function?

Comment: Why don't you make `size` another column in your data, so it is passed as part of the `apply`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add that vector as a column to your data frame (remove it later if you wish):

```
varespec['size'] = size
```

And then either change your `rare` function:

```
def rare(x):
    size = x['size']
    y = x.values[:-1]
    ...
```

Or if you don't want to change `rare`, wrap it:

```
def rare_wrapper(x):
    size = x['size']
    y = x.values[:-1]
    return rare(y, size)
```

Comment: This was actually the solution I've patched together for now. I was wondering if there was something more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You could express the result as a calculation on whole NumPy arrays, rather than one done by calling `rare` once for each row of `varespec`:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.rpy.common as com
import scipy.misc as misc
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

def rare(y, size):
    notabs = ~np.isnan(y)
    t = y[notabs]
    N = np.sum(t)
    diff = N - t
    rare = np.sum(1 - misc.comb(diff, size)/misc.comb(N, size))
    return rare

def using_rare(size):
    return np.array([rare(varespec.iloc[i,:], size[i]) for i in xrange(50)])

def using_arrays(size):    
    N = varespec.sum(axis='columns', skina=True)
    diff = (N[:, np.newaxis] - varespec.values).T
    return np.sum(1 - misc.comb(diff, size) / misc.comb(N, size), axis=0)

varespec = com.load_data('BCI', 'vegan')
size = np.random.randint(varespec.shape[1], size=(varespec.shape[0],))
```

This shows `using_rare` and `using_arrays` produce the same result:

```
expected = using_rare(size)
result = using_arrays(size)
assert np.allclose(result, expected)
```

---

```
In [229]: %timeit using_rare(size)
10 loops, best of 3: 36.2 ms per loop

In [230]: %timeit using_arrays(size)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.89 ms per loop
```

---

This takes advantage of the fact that `scipy.misc.comb` can accept NumPy arrays as input. So you can call `comb(diff, size)` where `diff` is an array of shape (225, 50) and `size` is an array of shape (50,). Since `size` is only used in the calls to `comb`, it is possible to perform all the calculations with just two calls to `comb`. No looping per row required.

Comment: I tried to come up with something like this myself but got stuck. Thanks!